Django messages without reloading the screen
So I am trying to show messages to the user by using django messages when they make any mistake, like trying to add product to a cart without selecting variation, now the problem is, these are all done by js, so if they don't refresh the screen, the users cannot see what mistake they have made.
So is there any way I can make django messages appear without reloading the page? If not, what are the alternatives?
My base.html:

        {% if messages %}
            <div class="container mt-3">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}" role="alert">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}

My views.py:

if product.has_variations and len(selected_variations) != variation_categories:
            messages.error(request, f"Please select all {variation_categories} variations.")
            return JsonResponse({'error': f'Please select all {variation_categories} variations.'}, status=400)

But this error message currently only appears after reloading the page.

That makes sense, since Django templates render at server side when requesting the page. You will need to work with some AJAX calls and expose an API to retrieve the messages.

It doesn't work with messages, but it's a sort-of equivalent thing - check out django-notifications.

All the alternatives look so complicated :')
